# How can I escape a room with no doors?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I've never been past level 4 and now I'm on level 13... then something teleported me and now here I am stuck.  There is lava on one side and walls on the other 3.  The wall to the left is only 1 block and then a big room (where I came from).  I can't use earthquake because there are no squares next to me to target.  I tried the holy hand grenade, with no luck, as well as a steam bolt bomb.

I found some debug switch and tried it, but when I press "P" to go up a floor the game just crashes.

Comment: Do you have a table and mirror?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eureka!  In debug mode you can click anywhere on the minimap and instantly teleport there.  FIXED!

Instructions for enabling debug mode: (From
http://dredmod.com/wiki/Debug_Mode)

> **Using Steam**
>
> 1. In your Steam Library, right click on Dungeons of Dredmor and select
>      "Properties".
> 2. On the General tab, press the "Set Launch Options" button.
> 3. In the dialog box, enter the text: **-debug-flag**
> 4. Press OK to close the start options.
> 5. Press Close to close the Properties window.
> 6. The game will now launch in debug mode every time until you remove
>      the -debug-flag from the launch options.
>
> **Using a shortcut in Windows**
>
> 1. Navigate to your Dungeons of Dredmor game folder using Windows.
> 2. Inside this folder you will see the file "Dungeons of Dredmor.exe".
>      This is the game executable.
> 3. Right-click on the game exe and select "Create Shortcut". This will
>      create a shortcut icon named "Shortcut to Dungeons of Dredmor.exe"
>      in this same folder.
> 4. Right-click on the shortcut and choose "Properties". This will open
>       the Properties window and should select the Shortcut tab.
> 5. In the Properties window on the Shortcut tab you will see a box
>       labeled "Target". It will contain the full path to game executable.
>       If the path contains spaces (e.g., "C:\Program Files...") then the
>       path will be surrounded in double quotes. These must be kept.
> 6. Click anywhere in the "Target" text box and press the "End" key on
>       your keyboard. This will move the cursor all the way to the end of
>       the box. You could also use the arrow keys to achieve this. The
>       cursor must be after the final double quote if there is one. With
>       the cursor at the end of the box, press the Spacebar key to add a
>       space then type in: -debug-flag The Target text box should now
>       contain something like: "C:\Program Files
>       (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\dungeons of dredmor\Dungeons of
>       Dredmor.exe" -debug-flag
> 7. Press the OK button in the Properties window to save this change
>       and close the window. Any time you want to launch the game in debug
>       mode you double click this shortcut rather than launching it the
>       normal way. You can move the shortcut to anywhere on your computer,
>       like the Desktop or your Start Menu, and you can rename it if you'd
>       like.

Comment: That's very good to know. I didn't realize debug mode did that.